# .Net Powerpoint Component

Tags: c#, .net, components, powerpoint

I am looking for a .Net component to allow reading and generation of powerpoint files. So far the only thing that I have been able to find is the component by [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx). Can anyone recommend other possible tools to use for this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10271255/1257567

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft Powerpoint Object Library which comes with Visual Studio. Heres an example of how to use it: [How to handle PowerPoint events with Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308825)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how complex can be your presentations, but using new [Office 2007 Open XML File Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx) you can create any Office document directly from managed code, without any other components.

Some time ago, I built an application which loads an Microsoft Project xml file and outputs its "Earned Value Analysis" (EVA) in a PPTX (Open XML PowerPoint format)

To get more informations, try this link: [Sample Open XML Documents](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/OpenXMLsamples.aspx)

Comment: You can also create the XML by hand, zip it, and rename it to pptx. That's not much more low-level than the OpenXml File Formats SDK.

Answer (score 0):

A necromancing recommendation: [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)

This project is the .NET version of POI Java project at http://poi.apache.org/. 
POI is an open source project which can help you read/write xls, doc, ppt files.